# Функция не работает в IE как исправить?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Доброго времени друзья! по нажатию ctrl+enter отправляется сообщение во всех браузерах кроме IE! Как исправить?

```
if(event.ctrlKey &&((event.keyCode == 0xA)||(event.keyCode==0xD))){
                var omena_val = $('#omena_msg').val();
               $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        crossDomain: true,
                        data: {
                                "key" : omena_val,
                                "key2" : hostName
                               },
                        url: "http://env-4522941.j.dnr.kz/omenaWorker.php",
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        success: function(data){
                              alert(data.key);
                        }
               });

              $('#omenaform').fadeOut(1000);
              $('#omena_msg').val("");
              $('#omenafirstForm').fadeIn(1000);
              $('#omenafirstForm:first').text("Отправлено! Чтобы написать еще, начните печатать снова.");
            }
        });
```

Comment: а вы какую версию jQuery используете?

Comment: jQuery v2.0.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[экстрасенс mode on]`

Вы `event` откуда берёте? В IE нет глобального объекта `event`, есть `window.event`. Поэтому лучше в начале обработчика вставить строку

```
var event = event || window.event;
```

А ещё лучше явно передавать обработчику объект события.

http://javascript.ru/tutorial/events/intro#obekt-sobytie-event

`[экстрасенс mode off]`

Answer (score -1):

попробуй заменить строчку

```
 if(event.ctrlKey &&((event.keyCode == 0xA)||(event.keyCode==0xD)||(event.keyCode==13))){
```

Comment: @Валентин Жуков, не советуйте ерунду. Чем, по-вашему, отличаются условия `(event.keyCode==0xD)` и `(event.keyCode==13)`?